# Unable to find Mono.Data.Sqlite library

Tags: sqlite, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I've been developing a web app going between Monodevelop (3.0.8) on my Linux box, and Monodevelop (now Xamarin Studio 4.0.3) on my Windows machine.

I'm using Sqlite for my database and it was working perfectly until I upgraded the Windows side to Xamarin 4.0.3 at which point Xamarin fails to locate the Mono.Data.Sqlite reference.  to the best of my knowledge, there was no change to the underlying Mono installation, although I have recently upgraded to Mono 3.0.9 on the Windows side and it still doesn't find it.  I only see Mono.Cairo, and Mono.Posix is my assembly list and the project still works correctly under Monodevelop on my Linux machine.

I do have a local copy of the Sqlite dll for Windows, but my goal is to develop across both platforms and not have to switch references around all the time.

This worked great before I upgraded on the Windows side.  Have I missed something in my configuration on the Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a matter of installing the Mono framework for me (http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html, I've used the latest stable, 2.10.9)

After it is installed (restart of Xamarin Studio might be necessary) you can set it as default in your Xamarin Studio (Tools -> Options, Projects -> .NET Runtimes) where it now appears next to the Microsoft .NET framework.

Comment: That was the setting I was looking for!  It kept complaining that it couldn't find the reference in .NET, but that wasn't what I had been wanting to target.  Mono was installed, but .NET was set as my default Runtime